# How does Post's theorem connect to concepts of universality and computability in theoretical computer science?

Tags: turing-machines

Since functional completeness is a kind of universality, there might be deep connections to other universal phenomena like Turing completeness.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they are formally related. Post's theorem concerns Boolean functions $\mathbb{B}^n \to \mathbb{B}$ (where $\mathbb{B} = \{0, 1\}$), which are always trivially computable by a Turing machine.

Differing concrete domains aside, in the abstract, Post's theorem is about finite lists of Boolean functions, whereas Turing completeness applies to a more general model of computation, not necessarily given as a finite list of operations. For example, [Conway's game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) is Turing complete, but this model of computation is not built from a finite list of functions like in Post's theorem. Post's theorem instead characterizes when a finite list of functions $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_k$ is expressively complete, i.e. can express all Boolean functions.

The closest analogy to Post's theorem in the context of computability would be if we can give an *exact characterization* of when a list of functions $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_k$ can express all Turing-computable functions. I'm not aware of such a *general* characterization, though I'm sure it has been studied! Of course, we have many *specific* examples: the lambda calculus operations ($\lambda$ abstraction and function application) are enough; WHILE programs (WHILE, IF THEN, and variable assignment) are enough; and so on. But I am not aware of any theorem of the form: you give me a list of functions or function constructors, and I'll tell you whether or not they are Turing-complete.